# WPF Does not display vertical scrollbar

Tags: c#, wpf

i am trying to create an application that will display user controls, based on information collected from DB. The problem is that if items total height exceeds mainwindow grid reserved for this display, i do not see a vertical scrollbar. From what i had found there might be an issue, that stackpanel/scrollviewer does not limit size of it's children. Im stuck on how to solve this, is there any way to stack items in limited spaces with scrollbar visible only when needed.
I want to avoid "hardcoding" the height of scrollviewer.
For now i'm stuck with below code:

XAML: (main window)

```
<Grid   Name="selectedOptionGrid"
        Grid.Column="1"
        Grid.Row="1"
        HorizontalAlignment="Left"
        VerticalAlignment="Top">
        <StackPanel Name="selectedOptionStack"/>
        <!-- Dock selected windows based on option selected-->
</Grid>
```

(user control, additional window docked to mainwindow)

```
<UserControl x:Class="Power_Planner_1._0.Team_Planner.MyTasks.ucTaskWindow"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Power_Planner_1._0.Team_Planner.MyTasks" 
             mc:Ignorable="d">
    <Grid Background="White"
          VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
          HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="20"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="5"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>

            <StackPanel Grid.Row="0"
                        Orientation="Horizontal"
                        VerticalAlignment="Top"
                        Margin="0,5,0,0">
                        <TextBlock Margin="60,0,0,0" Width="160" FontWeight="Bold">Task Name</TextBlock>
                        <TextBlock Margin="10,0,0,0" Width="160" FontWeight="Bold">Team Name</TextBlock>
                        <TextBlock Margin="0,0,0,0" Width="55" FontWeight="Bold">Deadline</TextBlock>
                        <TextBlock Margin="20,0,0,0" Width="60" FontWeight="Bold">Start</TextBlock>
                        <TextBlock Margin="28,0,0,0" Width="60" FontWeight="Bold">End</TextBlock>
                        <TextBlock Margin="20,0,0,0" Width="60" FontWeight="Bold">Run Time</TextBlock>
        </StackPanel>
            
            <Separator  Grid.Row="1"
                        VerticalAlignment="Top"/>

            <Grid   Name="taskListGrid"
                    Grid.Row="2"
                    Height="510"
                    Width="830">
                <ScrollViewer   VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
                                Width="{Binding ActualWidth,RelativeSource={RelativeSource 
                                Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=Grid}}"                   
                                Height="{Binding ActualHeight,RelativeSource={RelativeSource
                                Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=Grid}}">
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical"
                                    x:Name="taskListStack">
                        <StackPanel.Resources>
                            <Style TargetType="UserControl">
                                <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0,5,0,0"/>
                            </Style>
                        </StackPanel.Resources>
                    </StackPanel>
                </ScrollViewer>
            </Grid>



    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

And finally an Items that are created:

```
<UserControl x:Class="Power_Planner_1._0.Team_Planner.MyTasks.ucTaskItem"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Power_Planner_1._0.Team_Planner.MyTasks"
             xmlns:materialDesign="http://materialdesigninxaml.net/winfx/xaml/themes"
             mc:Ignorable="d" d:DesignHeight="45">
    <Border CornerRadius="12,12,12,12"
            BorderThickness="1,1,1,1"
            BorderBrush="LightGray"
            Background="#FF456780"
            Padding="0">
        <Grid>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="50"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="160"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="160"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="65"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="90"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="90"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="65"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <!--Picture-->
                <Border     Grid.Column="0"
                            CornerRadius="25,25,25,25"
                            BorderThickness="1,1,1,1"
                            Width="30"
                            Height="30"
                            BorderBrush="LightGray"
                            Background="ForestGreen"
                            HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                            Margin="10,0,0,0">
                </Border>
                <!--Task Name-->
                <TextBlock  Grid.Column="1"
                            Margin="10,0,0,0"
                            FontSize="12"
                            Foreground="LightGray"
                            Text="{Binding taskName}"
                            Width="160"
                            VerticalAlignment="Center">
                </TextBlock>
                <!--Team Name-->
                <TextBlock  Grid.Column="2"
                            Margin="20,0,0,0"
                            FontSize="12"
                            Foreground="LightGray"
                            Text="{Binding teamName}"
                            Width="160"
                            VerticalAlignment="Center">
                </TextBlock>
                <!--Deadline-->
                <TextBlock  Grid.Column="3"
                            Margin="20,0,0,0"
                            FontSize="12"
                            Foreground="LightGray"
                            Text="{Binding deadline}"
                            Width="45"
                            VerticalAlignment="Center">
                </TextBlock>
                <!--Start-->
                <Button Grid.Column="4"
                            Background="#FF456780"
                            BorderBrush="LightGray"
                            Height="25"
                            Margin="20,0,0,0"
                            Width="60">
                    <Button.Resources>
                        <Style TargetType="{x:Type Border}">
                            <Setter Property="CornerRadius" Value="10"/>
                        </Style>
                    </Button.Resources>
                <TextBlock Foreground="LightGray">Start</TextBlock>
                </Button>
                <!--Stop-->
                <Button Grid.Column="5"
                            Background="#FF456780"
                            BorderBrush="LightGray"
                            Height="25"
                            Margin="20,0,0,0"
                            Width="60">
                    <Button.Resources>
                        <Style TargetType="{x:Type Border}">
                            <Setter Property="CornerRadius" Value="10"/>
                        </Style>
                    </Button.Resources>
                    <TextBlock Foreground="LightGray">Stop</TextBlock>
                </Button>
                <!--Deadline-->
                <TextBlock  Grid.Column="6"
                            Margin="20,0,0,0"
                            FontSize="12"
                            Foreground="LightGray"
                            Text="{Binding runtime}"
                            Width="45"
                            VerticalAlignment="Center">
                </TextBlock>
                <!--Other Options-->
                <materialDesign:PopupBox    Grid.Column="7"
                                            StaysOpen="False" 
                                            Foreground="White"
                                            HorizontalAlignment="Right">
                    <StackPanel Width="150"
                                Background="White">
                        <Button Content="Edit"/>
                        <Button Content="View Details"/>
                        <Button Content="Comment"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                </materialDesign:PopupBox>
        </Grid>
    </Border>

</UserControl>
```

Code to add items:

```
taskListStack.Children.Clear();
var task1 = new clsTaskItem("Test1", "blablabla", "12:40", "02:30");
taskListStack.Children.Add(new ucTaskItem(task1));
var task2 = new clsTaskItem("Test2", "blablabla", "13:45");
taskListStack.Children.Add(new ucTaskItem(task2));
var task3 = new clsTaskItem("Test3", "blablabla", "11:45");
taskListStack.Children.Add(new ucTaskItem(task3));
var task4 = new clsTaskItem("Test4", "blablabla", "14:45");
taskListStack.Children.Add(new ucTaskItem(task4));
var task5 = new clsTaskItem("Test5", "blablabla", "17:45");
taskListStack.Children.Add(new ucTaskItem(task5));
var task6 = new clsTaskItem("Test6", "blablabla", "18:45");
taskListStack.Children.Add(new ucTaskItem(task6));
var task7 = new clsTaskItem("Test7", "blablabla", "13:23");
taskListStack.Children.Add(new ucTaskItem(task7));
var task8 = new clsTaskItem("Test8", "blablabla", "12:54");
taskListStack.Children.Add(new ucTaskItem(task8));
var task9 = new clsTaskItem("Test9", "blablabla", "17:23");
taskListStack.Children.Add(new ucTaskItem(task9));
var task10 = new clsTaskItem("Test10", "blablabla", "17:10");
taskListStack.Children.Add(new ucTaskItem(task10));
    taskListStack.Children.Add(new ucTaskItem(task1));
    taskListStack.Children.Add(new ucTaskItem(task2));
    taskListStack.Children.Add(new ucTaskItem(task3));
    taskListStack.Children.Add(new ucTaskItem(task4));
    taskListStack.Children.Add(new ucTaskItem(task5));
    taskListStack.Children.Add(new ucTaskItem(task6));
    taskListStack.Children.Add(new ucTaskItem(task7));
    taskListStack.Children.Add(new ucTaskItem(task8));
    taskListStack.Children.Add(new ucTaskItem(task9));
    taskListStack.Children.Add(new ucTaskItem(task10));
```

And task item class ( to which items are binded via datacontext)

```
public class clsTaskItem
{
    public clsTaskItem(string tsname, string tmname, string dline, string rtime = "00:00:00")
    {
        taskName = tsname;
        teamName = tmname;
        deadline = dline;
        runtime = rtime;
    }

    public string taskName  { get; private set; }
    public string teamName  { get; private set; }
    public string deadline  { get; private set; }
    public string runtime   { get; private set; }
}
```

As you can see i had tried to bind the scrollviewer height to grid i had created on top of it, thinking that if i set height to auto, it will get the height from the grid actual height. Well that didn't make much sense hence it was not working. I'm trying to find another solution for grouping the items, that way that i could expand easily main window, without coding each window to expand with this expansion so that items would both fill all available space and display scrollbar when needed.

Please help :)

Comment: You need to constraint the height of the `ScollViewer` somewhere. Where is `ucTaskItem` hosted in the window?

Comment: ucTaskWindow is docked on MainWindow and ucTaskItem is docked to ucTaskWindow i had modified it a bit and tried to do it with DockPanel. Unfortunately im stuck at same problem, funny thing DockPanel works grear if it were width problem, but does not work on height.

Comment: other thing, i wanted to achieve it without height declaration :)

Comment: As mentioned, the height needs to be constrained somewhere in the element tree.